# How to write a custom pattern validator in Angular Dart 2

Tags: dart, angular-dart

How to  write a  custom validator in Angular Dart 2.   Is there a  working example of a  validator with parameters  and how to use it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can see the pattern validator here: https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/706c1b634443cfe2ba60b6ab37e2a536078ed00a/angular_forms/lib/src/directives/validators.dart#L165